# Slide menu android

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, slide, layer

I'm trying to replicate the sliding menu has been used in linked in. but the problem is I can't move the layer to the parent which doesn't have the action bar.

xml file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".SportListActivity" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#020202"
    android:divider="#f2f2f2"
    android:orientation="vertical"                      
    >
     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menu_listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#010101"
        android:dividerHeight="2dip" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sport_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sport_status_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="@string/sport_progress"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/sport_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</merge>
```

and when I run it. it looks like the images below as you can see the black area should be outside of the border with action bar. So now the question is how I can move the menu area to left side of the action bar?

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3zHm0xuvhEQRTdlcGl6R0tLQWc/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3zHm0xuvhEQOFFIUENqVm8wdWs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: Have you tried using the official Google version to do that? Google released the Navigation Drawer pattern at I/O 2013 and has updated the version 4 support library to include this. :)

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html